# How do I keep this VCCS stable?

Tags: current-source, instrumentation-amplifier

I have designed a circuit to measure impedance of certain tissues. It injects a constant current from two electrodes and measures the voltage at different electrodes. The system mainly consists of a frequency generator, voltage controlled current source, some multiplexers connecting the electrodes and then the measurement circuitry.
[image: Schematic of the VCCS]
When I connect different resistors between OUTA and OUTB I can verify the circuit is behaving as expected. However, when I connected the secondary board with multiplexers, the output suddenly changes to a distorted waveform centered around 5V.  The same occurs if I bring my hand close enough to the OUTA terminal. This does not recover until I restart the frequency generator.

Comment: Can you prove the system is stable, if the switches are not switching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a pinpoint comment which brings up the key concept: the stability. You have designed a feedback loop which tries to push AC as a constant current source. Capacitive load causes immediately 90 degrees phase lag and that can be enough to make your loop an oscillator when added to already existing phase lag.

Your options:

- reduce the gain at high frequencies DIFFICULT! Causes easily more phase lag.
- insert a permanent minimum load resistor and take it into the account in the calculations. That resistor hopefully reduces the phase lag caused by the capacitance.
- redesign the regulation to work in DC mode ie. the current is forced to have amplitude which causes the right peak voltage to the current sense resistor

ADD: The case is extremely complex. Capacitive load affects more at the lowermost end of your current sense resistor, but if we assume the differential amplifier function still be valid at high frequencies, the current sense voltage is actually RC high pass filtered. There's a slight possiblity to compensate the case by adding a small capacitor in parallel with the current sense resistor. No quarantee, but easy to test.

More complexity is caused by the fact that wirings have also inductance. There can be parasitic resonance circuits at megaherzes or tens of megaherzes. DC mode regulation would solve HF phase problems.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the phase lag issue. Looks like I need to revisit signals and systems.

Comment: I changed the ref voltage of InAmp and forced the output to have a DC bias and it seems to work well to some extent.

Answer (score 1):

Impedance Converter or Network Analyzer chips widely used for impedance measurement. for example, Ad5933 can be used for impedance measurement. In the application note, you can find an extra circuit for small signal measurement. The IC control any data path and you can measure impedance over a high bandwidth.

Comment: I was looking for a way to do both 'two pole' and 'four pole' measurements, that's why I tried to roll my own design. Should have researched a bit more about off the shelf solutions.

Comment: @chamod if you have impedance and its phase with frequency, then you can estimate the circuit model of system.

Comment: @chamod this is an advanced solution. I recommend to check if its range fits your purposes. I bet complex impedance vs fequency is needed for deeper electrochemical behaviour analyses, not only its magnitude.